# Как выключить контроллер USB в Ubuntu на VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Хотел узнать с помощью какой команды можно выключить контроллер USB в Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: виртуалбокс на убунту или убунту на виртуалбоксе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри lsusb там несколько хабов, например:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Вырубить драйвер хаба можно командой

```
echo "3-0:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-0\:1.0/driver/unbind
```

Все устройсва на Bus отключаются.
Притом на большинстве материнок питание устройства сбрасывается. Но при перевтыке устройства питание возвращается. В системе устройства на этом хабе не появятся.